# Fragment transaction with SetCustomAnimations crashes on back pressed: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-animation

I am making an android app with Xamarin. In one of my activities I have a frame layout that I put fragments in. In the transaction I use `SetCustomAnimations()`, `Replace()`, and `AddToBackStack()`. When I press the back button or call `OnBackPressed()`, the app crashes with the exception:

> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
>   You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

If I remove the call to `SetCustomAnimations()` it works, but I don't get any animations.

The activity:

```
[Android.App.Activity(Label = "Login")]
public class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private FrameLayout view;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        view = new FrameLayout(this)
        {
            Id = View.GenerateViewId()
        };

        SetContentView(view);

        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(view.Id, SelectDomainFragment.Create()).Commit();
    }

    public void ShowFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
            .SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.enter_right, Resource.Animation.exit_left, Resource.Animation.enter_left, Resource.Animation.exit_right)
            .Replace(view.Id, fragment)
            .AddToBackStack(null)
            .Commit();
    }    
}
```

SelectDomainFragment:

```
public class SelectDomainFragment : Fragment
{
    private SelectDomainView view;

    public static SelectDomainFragment Create() => new SelectDomainFragment();

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        view = new SelectDomainView(Context);

        view.CloudButtonClicked += (sender, e) => ToLogin(1);
        view.OnPremButtonClicked += (sender, e) => ToLogin(2);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) => view;        

    private void ToLogin(int target) => ((LoginActivity)Activity).ShowFragment(LoginFragment.Create(target));
}
```

LoginFragment:

```
public class LoginFragment : Fragment
{
    private LoginView view;

    public static LoginFragment Create(int target)
    {
        var args = new Bundle();
        args.PutInt("target", target);

        return new LoginFragment
        {
            Arguments = args
        };
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        view = new LoginView(Context);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) => view;

}
```

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test with it?